# How do you make a responsive site without media-queries?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

For the life of me, I can't quite figure out how this template is responsive without any extensive use of media-queries.

https://02dc74ce3e31e56a52ebcc845dca58e87283aabe.googledrive.com/host/0Bxbofwq0kd4ReUt2YWVOYmt3WVU/

Anyone have any ideas?

I bought this template, and the responsiveness kinda broke while I was applying it and the author is not responding to emails.

I can't quite figure out how this looks so elegant on small screens particularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set `max-width` to prevent an element to be wider than required on large screens. Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ur3futxp/

Answer (score 3):

A webpage doesn't need to use media queries to be responsive. Responsive by definition means the elements adapt or "respond" to your device or screen size, instead of using a fixed or pre-defined width/height/arrangement regardless of the viewing device.

The link you pasted is certainly a "responsive" site, and they achieve this by allowing elements to have a fluid width (only with a max-width on the container, to make sure it doesn't keep growing if you have a very large screen, since that would look funny).

The way they do it makes your CSS code very simple and uncluttered from various viewport pixel definitions and media queries.

Answer (score 1):

The site uses twitter bootstrap to make the site responsive. Bootstrap by default makes a site responsive using media queries if you use it grid system. Please refer the documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

This site is using twitter bootstrap framework which is developed to make the site responsive with all the devices without using any media queries as it already have predefined all the media queries in its framework and if you want to any more things to get responsive you must add your classes in your style.css file and make it sure that it will not conflict with twitter bootstrap predefined classes and you can do that by reviewing this site

http://getbootstrap.com